# How to install the Docker image into ECR using Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins

I can't find a right solution here.
I got installed Jenkins on EC2 where I added a pipeline with link to the github where I have repository with docker-compose.yml file.

How to install this image of docker into ECR on AWS.

Comment: you can build an image on Jenkins then push image to ECR

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation on pushing to ECR is available here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html)

The steps are:

1. Authenticate docker with ECR
2. Build your docker image
3. tag the docker image with the required ECR format:

   ```
   docker tag <image>:<version> <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<image>:<version>
   ```
4. docker push <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr..amazonaws.com/

The simplest way to accomplish this is with a shell script.  There are also jenkins plugins that will do this for you.

Comment: Where can I find a example of a shell script? The second question is, which one jenkins plugins it is?